# Google Translate API: Translates symbols to Gibberish - Python

Tags: excel, python-3.x, google-translate

I am using Google Translate API to translate a excel column from Japanese to English. The Japanese column not only contains Japanese characters but some numeric symbols like ①, ⑥ etc.

No problem in translating the Japanese characters but the symbols gets converted into a gibberish.
Example:
Japanese: ＃⑥その他
English:  # â‘¥ Other

But the same text works fine with Google Translate Web

[image]

How to prevent translating symbols in Google Translate API?

Comment: More likely than not, symbols occupy a specific range of Unicode numbers which you might remove from the original text before giving it for translation.

Answer (score 0):

The issue comes from mixing numeric symbols with a language, since then it's harder for the Translation API to detect which is the source language.

I don't know which method you are using to call the Translation API, but in any case, **specifying the source language solves the issue**.

For example, with a REST call from the Command Line Interface:

```
curl -X POST -H "Authorization: Bearer "\
$(gcloud auth application-default print-access-token) \
-H "Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8" --data "{
  'q': '＃⑥その他',
  'source': 'ja',
  'target': 'en'
}" "https://translation.googleapis.com/language/translate/v2"
```

Will return `"# ⑥ Other"` as the result of the translation.